# Is the PARTIAL regression coefficient always smaller than the SIMPLE regression coefficient (when all variables are positively correlated)?

Tags: multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, partial-effect

Suppose we have three variables: X1, X2, and Y. X1 and X2 are the independent variables (IVs) and Y is the dependent variable (DV). Suppose that each IV is positively associated with the DV. Suppose also that each IV is positively associated with the other IV. In other words, X1, X2 and Y are all positively associated.

Now in scenario 1 we regress Y on X1 alone and get a **simple** regression coefficient for **X1**. In scenario 2 we regress Y on **both** X1 **and** X2 and get a **partial** regression coefficient for **X1**.

My question, then, is this: will the **partial** regression coefficient for X1 always be *smaller* than the **simple** regression coefficient for X1?

[Note: I'm asking about the particular case in which there are two independent variables (X1 and X2) and **all three variables are positively associated**.]

I've discussed this question with a couple of people who have a better grasp of stats than I do. But the problem is that one of them said the answer was "Yes" whilst the other said the answer was "No." One person based the answer on algebra; the other based it on geometry (which I couldn't understand).

I've tried to work out the answer to the question by using the formulas for the simple regression coefficient and partial regression coefficient (since I generally understand algebra better than geometry):

**Simple regression coefficient:

[image]

OR

[image]

Partial regression coefficient:**

[image]

Analysis of these formulas has however not helped me work out the answer to the question.

Comment: Please type your question as text, do not just post a 
photograph or screenshot (see [here](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3176/)). 
When you retype the question, add the [tag:self-study] tag 
& read [its wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). 
Then tell us what you understand thus far, what you've 
tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to help 
you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.

Comment: This isn't my homework and I'm not hoping someone will "do it for me." I'm an adult looking for insights into this issue. Also, I have typed my question as text. The only "photographs" I have inserted are screenshots of the formulas. I do not have software that allows me to type formulas by hand and see no reason to do so if I can just paste a screenshot of those formulas.

Comment: OK, but this site supports $\LaTeX$ markup which do not require any special software.  For information on how see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Fine, but I'm working a full-time job at the moment and don't really have the time to learn how to use that system. It's simpler just to copy and paste the three formulae. Hopefully you'll allow that to stand as I'm keen to learn the answer to my question. If I get the time, I'll go through the tutorial page you've linked to. But I would be grateful if you would allow my past to stand.